# Python: Print elements using map function

Tags: python, map-function

I'm new to Python and I'm learning how to use `map` function. I run into following issue:

```
li=['12','34']
ints=map(int,li)
list(ints) #prints [12,34] OK
p1 = map(print,list(ints))
list(p1)   #prints [] WHY?
p2 = map(print, li)
list(p2)   #prints 12 34 [None, None] OK
```

I just map `print` function to list of strings and list of integers and got different result. I cannot see why would `p1` and `p2` behave differently.

Comment: I just answered a question related to this, take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55844520/1695172

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying map on dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844489/applying-map-on-dictionaries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns a map object that when exhausted will yield not values. So, when you call `list` the second time to `ints` it will not be able to apply the funtion to nothing so then `list(map(print,list(ints)))` will return an empty list`[]`

Check what happens when applying `list` twice to the same map object:

```
>>> li=['12','34']
>>> ints=map(int,li)
>>> ints
<map object at 0x7f4e375c7898>
>>> list(ints)
[12, 34]
>>> list(ints)
[]
```

Comment: I got it. Problem is because I use `list(ints)` twice. But how to create list multiple times from ienumerable collection? For example, in C# you can call ToList() on IEnumerable and get new list on every call.

Comment: @Dejan, you can use `itertools.tee` to "copy" the iterator, but in this case is just better to call the same maping again or just have a it in a list and use the list.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link for map|filter|reduce
http://dataunbox.com/course/24/118/Python%20for%20dummies
To answer your question map function takes list.but you have provided list(list))

```
li=['12','34']

ints=list(map(lambda x : x,li))
print(ints)

p1 = map(print,ints) ## instead of int probabaly you might have to provide li
list(p1)   #prints [] WHY?
```

Comment: that map is not converting the strings to ints